# Showing Chinese localization characters using unicode resource file

Tags: java, unicode, localization, chinese-locale

I have a Java Application supporting multiple locales using resource bundle files. The application is currently translated to Spanish, Italian, Portuguese and Simplified Chinese.

When testing the translations the application is launched with

```
 javaw -Duser.language=zh -Duser.country=CN  ...
```

This display correct for all languages except Chinese. However, after some testing I see that the application title show correct and tool-tip text. 
An example of my test for a Label:

```
    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 70, 70));
    jLabel3.setText(bundle.getString("Password")); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setToolTipText(bundle.getString("Password")); // NOI18N
```

The unicode for Password is

```
 Password=\u5bc6\u7801
```

The tooltip text and dialog title display correct but not the label or button text. They show squares with a "?" inside. I don't have 10 reputation so I can't post an image.

Environment:
OS: Windows 7 64bit; NetBeans IDE 8.0.2; JDK 1.7

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Calibri font does not have characters \u5bc6\u7801. At least on my Windows 8.1 installation. You can check if you have it installed using "charmap.exe". Try another font. Arial contains character \u5bc6 on my default installation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried with both Tahoma and Arial but still didn't show. One difference though: Instead of a square with a "?" inside it was just a square.

Comment: I printed out the font used by ToolTip (SansSerif) and changed my label and button --> Now all characters show as expected for all languages. 
I guess I will have to change Calibri to SansSerif evrywhere. Any suggestions to do this automatically in NetBeans?